# How do I beat the Golem Boss in Tymmer Palace Ruins in Agarest - Generations of War ZERO?

Tags: record-of-agarest-war-zero

My party consists of Zeeg, Linda, Rouiter, Mimel, Alice and Sayane. The problem that I keep having is that I have to deal with those 3 Mieshas, because they can perfectly avoid all attacks. But when their HP drops to **25% or below**, I can only kill them with Special Moves, but Rouiter is too weak to deal enough damage, Alice and Linda's skills get absorbed and I have to kill them in one turn or they will recover HP.

Even after I do that the Golems have that Swing attack that kills everyone in one hit.  I try my best to keep everyone linked cause then even if Alice or Rouiter can't target anyone with the links they can still heal. I have 20 Fragments of Life but because of how much those 2 Golems and the Meisha deal to me, I can end up going though half of them. I want to keep everyone alive so that they all get the massive amount of EXP for beating the boss.

Everyone is Level 27. Zerg has the Sword of Kings at level 5, Linda has the Divine Lance at level 1, and Alice has that Staff which you can by from the adventure Guild for 350 TP (can't remember it's name) at Level 5. Everyone is wearing Platium Bracelets at Level 5.

I need to know at what kind of level should I be at to beat this boss? What kind of equipment should I have? I'd appreciate any tips for beating the battle (the only thing I can think of is to not let one of the Golems make its move with 25% or less HP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to beat it, here's what i did

Before the battle:
top up on Fragments of Life, make sure everyone has the best Defense Armour they can get, the battle frame is good but give this to Zeeg since he will most likely be taking the brunt of the attacks and the Meisha are going to kill him with magic anyway even with level 5 platinum bracelets, also, make sure everyone has their second Special Move, these are more powerful, have better break values and a couple are just ever better.

NOTE: this answer is based off from ym question so this may not work if you use a different party or if Zeeg is a mage or something

I had everyone group around Zeeg using the link with him in the center, Mimel and Linda in the front, Alice right behind him and Routier in the back to his right and Sayane linked in some way.

the strategy is to try and prevent the Golems from attacking as much as possible while making sure that they never get to attack when their HP is bellow 25%

First and it always seems like this, the Miesha and Golems gang up on Zeeg to deal close to 20,000 damage, this will waste all their AP, the moment Mimel or Alice get their turn have them use a Fragment of Life since Zeeg is the key to the entire group being links.

next, proceed in trying to kill the Meisha leaving any Special Moves as the last attack, because of my equipment, i only had Zeeg's and Mimel's attacks to deal any good damage, UNDER NO REASON USE SAYANE'S SPECIAL MOVE, this will be explained later.

try and keep everyone in the same positions and kill the Meisha, because of their healing you have to kill them in one turn but the next turn they wont do as much damage cause they used up their AP to heal, however they may still get the Golems to attack.

have Sayane attack at a range and try and keep her alive, when she has the AP and 100 SP, have her use her second special move making sure the targets are BOTH Golems, the attack will disable the golems preventing them from attacking or countering

Once the Meisha have been killed the real battle starts, hopefully the Golems are still disabled, keep Sayane attacking so she can build up her SP but making sure that you don't deplete her AP to a point where it will take a couple of turns to build up to use her second special move, best way to do this is getting to use no more than 20 AP, also, keep Rouiter from using her special moves, her second one can boost SP and may come in handy if Sayane hasn't got enough SP to pull off her special move when the Golems recover from their disabled status

The Golems should recover after 5 turns, i wasn't counting, however if you keep one person in between them who could possible survive their attacks, they will target them, try as much to keep everyone out of the range of the Golem's swing attack, while some may survive, you need Sayane to disable both ASAP when they recover and you can't waist time resurrecting everyone.

focus attacks on one Golem at a time, when one is close to 25% of it's HP, throw everything you got, best way to do this is to make sure your not deleting your SP and AP so when you throw everything at the Golem, Zeeg, Mimel and Linda can pull off their second Special Moves, this will bring the break down on the Golem by a fair bit, add Routier's and Alice's Special Move and you may break the Golem, any defence bonus he has because of his HP dropping bellow 25% will mean nothing, if your AP maxed out before you began the attacks, your character should have enough AP to throw some combo attacks, tyr and focus on magic as the Golems have weaker Res than Def, quite possible, you'll end up doing 20,000 damage in this final attack on a golem.

with one dead, the other will be slightly easier, keep up Sayane's attacks and disabling of the Golem.

while the golems are disabled, you can use this chance to have Alice and Rouiter Heal, it's better to do this when it's Alice's turn cause by the time she has her second Speical Move she cant target almost everyone in the area, if everyone is hurt and Alice as the SP for it, have her use her second special move since it recovers all.

after the battle is over, get on your knees and pray to what ever phantom you worship as a god that the power doesn't go out until you can save, the battle is hard enough without having to do it a second time

Understand this is what i did on the weekend and it's not a step by step how to, it's guidance, some things in this may work with you, some wont, the key points to this are

- Sayane having her second special move as it disables
- having the Meisha and Golems waste their AP on a character that can be brough back the very next chance you get
- Not allowing the golems to attack when their HP be bellow 25% to avoid that Attack Boost, it's bad enough they can kill in one turn without it